# How to add form button to card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a `card-link` to my Bootstrap `card` but this link needs to be a `DELETE` request (for my resource controller).

I am aware that I could use JavaScript to solve my problems but I would like to instead use a form to submit.

I have currently tried the following:

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$site->cover}}" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{$site->title}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{str_limit($site->description, 300)}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block text-right">
        <a href="#" class="card-link text-primary">Edit</a>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.site.destroy', ['site' => $site])}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <button type="submit" class="card-link text-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The edit link renders perfectly well (as a button) but the delete button does not render as a `card-link`.

[image: Current layout]

So my question, how do I put non-get-request links inside bootstrap card links.

Comment: The only valid attributes for `method` are `get | post`.

Comment: @RobertC sorry mistake from my side although this does not change the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is how Bootstrap (and browsers) handle the `<button>` tag and `<form>` in general.  There are some structural changes that help bypass this though, the first of which is moving the basic `<form>` elements outside of `.card-block`.

From there we're going to apply some `.btn` related classes to your `<button>` to remove its basic styling: `.btn-link` works nicely here.

The only thing missing is that the `<button>` won't default to a pointer cursor, so you'll want to make sure to address that for UI/UX concerns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.site.destroy', ['site' => $site])}}" class="pull-right">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%" />
    
    <div class="card-block">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{$site->title}}</h4>
  <p class="card-text">{{str_limit($site->description, 300)}}</p>
    </div>

 <div class="card-block text-right">
  <a href="#" class="card-link text-primary">Edit</a>
  <button type="submit" class="card-link btn-link text-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>

 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A simple `button.card-link { cursor: pointer; }` solved the UX problem, for now this works perfectly. How would the same theoretically work for multiple different links inside a single card?

Comment: `.card-link` already forces these links to display inline, so I presume adding more to the same area would be fine.  You could also combine it with `.btn-group`

Comment: This does indeed work, my question was more intended toward needing multiple forms for lets say an update and a delete request from multiple card links

Comment: In that situation you'd probably need to wrap your entire form element; perhaps using the Bootstrap Grid or a simple float. For ease-of-use I'd probably avoid the form entirely.